# Split the data into training and test sets

Tags: python, kaggle

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
train = pd.read_csv('/Users/..../Desktop/train.csv')
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

So i'm stuck on how to make a 70/30 split on train/test... this is based on job salary prediction on kaggle using ipython

Comment: where is your code for splitting? please provide that as well.

Comment: [The help file has an example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html)

Answer (score 0):

if `Data` holds all your Datasets (independents and dependants) in a numpy array:
in this way

```
Data=([[1, 2, 3, 430],[...]...])
```

3 independents and one dependent

you can set the indices for slicing like that:

```
test_ind=int(Data.shape[0]*0.3)
train_ind=Data.shape[0]-test_ind
```

`Data[:train_ind,:4]` would be your training data
`Data[train_ind:,:4]` would be your test data